# How to make a case condition inside codeigniter query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have some query like this :

```
$this->db->query("SELECT `no_request`,`date_in`,`location`,`d_point`,`username`,SUM(request.`persen`) AS 'Persen',
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(Persen) = 0 THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN SUM(persen) = 100 THEN 'Complete'
            WHEN SUM(persen) > 0 AND SUM(persen) < 100 THEN 'On Process'
        END AS 'states'
        FROM request WHERE `location` = '$lokasi' GROUP BY `no_request`
        HAVING 
        CASE 
            WHEN `Persen` = 0 THEN `states` = 'Pending'
        END", TRUE)->result_array();
```

I want make query original from codeigniter but i have some problem with my query :

```
$this->db->select($this->fetching_column);
$this->db->select_sum($this->persen);
$this->db->select("
CASE
  WHEN SUM('persen') = 0 THEN 'Pending'
  WHEN SUM('persen') = 100 THEN 'Complete'
  WHEN SUM('persen') > 0 SUM('persen') < 100 THEN 'On Process'
END", FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->where($this->location . ' = ' . $location);
$this->db->group_by($this->group);

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Is my query is wrong?, or I can't use `case` inside `$this->db->select()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->db->select()` acknowledges a discretionary second parameter. In the event that you set it to **FALSE**, **CodeIgniter** won't attempt to ensure your field or table names. This is helpful on the off chance that you need a compound select explanation where programmed getting away of fields may break them.

for reference:- https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: so I must to delete **FALSE** inside that query?, or something code to make my query work?

Answer (score 0):

I have make a some fault in my query to make my query isn't working, but now is code is fine and I already done with my code, I change my query like this :

**From this code :**

```
$this->db->select($this->fetching_column);
$this->db->select_sum($this->persen);
$this->db->select("
CASE
  WHEN SUM('persen') = 0 THEN 'Pending'
  WHEN SUM('persen') = 100 THEN 'Complete'
  WHEN SUM('persen') > 0 SUM('persen') < 100 THEN 'On Process'
END", FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->where($this->location . ' = ' . $location);
$this->db->group_by($this->group);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

**Became like this :**

```
$this->db->select($this->fetching_column);
$this->db->select_sum($this->persen, 'Persen');
$this->db->select("
  CASE 
    WHEN SUM(Persen) = 0 THEN 'Pending'
    WHEN SUM(Persen) = 100 THEN 'Complete'
    WHEN SUM(Persen) > 0 AND SUM(Persen) < 100 THEN 'On Process'
  END AS 'states'");
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->where($this->location, $location);
$this->db->group_by($this->group);
$result = $this->db->get();
```